# How can I use one std::thread object to run 2 sequential events (functions)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mfc

My project is a MFC dialog. There is a "Installation" button. Users can click this button to start a download and to automatically exectue the installation after download finished.

[image]

I have already fulfilled the download part -- in a std::thread. When users click the "Installation" button, it would prompt a progress bar, it's actually is another CDailog - It's called CMyProgressBar.

```
CMyProgressBar has a member m_thDownload.

void CMyProgressBar::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    m_thDownload = std::thread(funDownload);
}
```

Here m_thDownload can do the download thing. After the download, I need a thread to execute the installation. I don't want to add another thread member, and actually I don't have to add another thread according to logic.

So, where do I put the starting installation code? and it can execute immediately after the download?

Comment: Why not just have the code sequentially in the function? `void runThread() { download(); install(); }` ?

Answer (score 3):

Create one function that runs both of those functions, then run *that* function in a thread.

```
void funDownloadAndInstall() {
    funDownload();
    funInstall();
}

m_thDownload = std::thread(funDownloadAndInstall);
```

You can also use a lambda expression:

```
m_thDownload = std::thread([]() {
    funDownload();
    funInstall();
});
```

Also, I'm not very familiar with MFC, but `DoDataExchange` seems like the wrong place to be starting threads. What if it gets called more than once, or not at all?

Comment: You are right. `DoDataExchange` gets called twice. on create and `OnOK`the dialog. Better to make it a new member with control or a maybe `OnInitDialog`